# insert data to the database from csv file

Tags: csv, laravel

i am trying to insert data from the csv excel file to the database but the code seem not to work,
i don't know where am doing wrong.

**here is my code:**

```
    public function postUploadS(){

    $file = array('file' => Input::file('file'));

    $rule = array('file' => 'required');
    $mime = array(  'text/csv',
                    'text/plain',
                    'application/csv',
                    'text/comma-separated-values',
                    'application/excel',
                    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                    'application/vnd.msexcel'
                );
    $uploaded_mime = Input::file('file')->getMimeType();



    $staff_list=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $linecount = "";
    $cols = 5;
    $numx ="";
    $mimes = array(
                    'text/csv',
                    'application/csv',
                    'text/comma-separated-values',
                    'application/excel',
                    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                    'application/vnd.msexcel',);

        if(empty($staff_list)){
                $_SESSION['error']="<font color='#FF0000'>Please choose the csv file to upload</font>";
                }

        elseif(!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $mimes)) {
                $_SESSION['error']="<font color='#FF0000'>Invalid file format, Please choose only csv exel format</font>";

                }

        else{
            $staff_list=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

            $handle=fopen($staff_list,"r");

            // read the first line and ignore it
            fgets($handle); 

            //count number of lines of uploaded csv file

             $fh = fopen($staff_list,'rb') or die("ERROR OPENING DATA");
                    while (fgets($fh) !== false) $linecount++;
                         fclose($fh);


            var_dump($fh); exit();

            while(($fileop=fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false){


                $fullname = $fileop[1];
                $staff_id = $fileop[0];
                $gender = $fileop[2];
                $position= $fileop[3];
                $department= $fileop[4];
                $numx = count($fileop);

                $tfulname = trim($fullname);
                $lfulname = strtolower($tfulname);

                $name_full = explode(' ', $lfulname);

                $firstname  = $name_full[0];
                $middlename = implode(array_slice($name_full, 1, -1));
                $lastname   = end($name_full);
                $phone = '';
                $email = '';
                $college = '';

                if($gender == 'M'){
                    $gender == 'Male';

                }
                elseif ($gender =='F') {
                    $gender == 'Female';
                }


        DB::beginTransaction();

    try{
        $staff = new Staff;
        $staff->staff_id = $staff_id;
        $staff->firstname = $firstname;
        $staff->middlename = $middlename;
        $staff->lastname = $lastname;
        $staff->gender = $gender;
        $staff->position = $position;
        $staff->phone = $phone;
        $staff->email = $email;
        $staff->college = $college;
        $staff->department = $department;
        $staff->save();

    }
    catch(Exception $e){

        Session::put('key','There is a duplicate row in your data,check the file and try again');
    }

        $cPass = ucfirst($lastname);    
        $hashed_pass = Hash::make($cPass);

        $user = new User;
        $user->username = $staff_id;
        $user->password = $hashed_pass;
        $user->save();


        }


        if($numx!=$cols){
                DB::rollback();
                    Session::put("error","<font color='#FF0000'>Error,number of columns does not match the defined value,please check your file and try again</font>");
                        }

        elseif(Session::has('key')){
                    DB::rollback();
                    Session::put("error","<font color='#FF0000'>Error,duplicate entry detected in your file,please check your file and try again</font>");
                    }

        else{

                DB::commit();
                Session::put("success","<font color='#0099FF'>Staff list has been uploaded successfully</font>");

                            }
```

}
    }

**when i run above code no data is inserted and i don't get any error. help please**

Comment: if you are using Laravel you can use "$csv->fetchAll()" like that.why didn't you try it?

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = Reader::createFromPath('path-to-your-file');

$result = $file->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $data){
// do database add here
}
```